# Is it 'easy' to cause a MD5 collision?

Tags: hash-collision

From [this page it appears you can do 5 billion hashes per second](http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm). Does this mean it is not difficult to cause a collision? If I wanted to create a file with a specific MD5 or SHA1 how long might it take?

According to my math (using 2^160) it'd still take a long time but from what I hear it isn't 2^160 to brute force a 160bit sha1 hash

Comment: http://th.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/people/lucks/HashCollisions/

Comment: FWIW that link claims they were able to find a collision in "just a few hours."

Comment: Yeah that confused me. And it appears to be in 2005. The MD5s of the two files are the same even tho SHA and such are different

Comment: Why's that confusing?  The whole point is that MD5 allows collisions on totally different input; why would SHA have the same flaw for the same files when it's a totally different algorithm?

Comment: For the sake of argument, imagine I create my own hashing algorithm which simply returns the number of bytes in a file.  You can see how it would be easy to create collisions, but there's no reason to expect that items that collide with my hashing algorithm would collide with MD5 or SHA.

Comment: The answer was unambiguously yes at least as of 2008, taking "a few hours". To rub this in in dramatic fashion, see the [Nostradamus Attack on PS3](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/Nostradamus/), where the winner of the 2008 US Presidential Election was "predicted" by crafting a _dozen_ files, each with a different winner's name but all hashing to the same MD5 hash.

Comment: @emodendroket: I meant its confusing that it can be in a few hours in 2005. And that I can see its different files bc I see the SHA being different

Answer (score 0):

If 5 billion hashes per second was true, it means you could create / "reverse" a hash in roughly **45 211 226 851 851 851 851 852 years** *(so you'll better start while you're still young)*.

## The maths behind this assumption

- An MD5 hash has 2^128 possible combinations
- 5 billion per second means **number of seconds =** 2^128 / (5 * 10^9)
- Which is about 10^30 seconds
- Which is about 45 211 226 851 851 851 851 852 years

**Conclusion:** You would need 3 trillion computers, start with the big bang - and today you would have your MD5 hash.

## Brute forcing and cryptography

When it comes to cryptography, brute forcing is **never** the answer. Once it is, it simply means that the cryptographic algorithm isn't strong enough, i.e. doesn't have enough bits. This happened to [DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard), which had a 56 bit key - and that just wasn't enough.

Also, mind you, that 256 bit is not "the double of" 128 bit! 256 bit is actually 2^128 times the amount of 128 bit.

```
2^256 / 2^128 = 2^128
```

## How MD5 collisions are still made!

So with brute forcing, you will not go anywhere, ever! No matter how many computers you have. The only option left is to attack the algorithm by mathematics.

Crypto analysts and mathematicians all over the world put research into this.

They managed to create an MD5 collision within a reasonable amount of time by cracking the algorithm. Don't ask me how they managed this, but here's an example:

```
d131dd02c5e6eec4 693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab 4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b302 83e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99f d91dbdf280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5b ae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd 02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8 ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a88393 96f9652b6ff72a70
```

has the same MD5 as

```
d131dd02c5e6eec4 693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab 4004583eb8fb7f89
55ad340609f4b302 83e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99f d91dbd7280373c5b
d8823e3156348f5b ae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd 02396306d248cda0
e99f33420f577ee8 ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a88393 96f965ab6ff72a70
```

## A flaw: rainbow tables

So you can't reverse a hash, but there are rainbow tables like [**md5cracker**](http://md5cracker.org/). They have a huge database of strings (usually passwords) and their hashes. So if you use a simple password, you can look up the hash there.

Try to look up this hash:

> 5a8dd3ad0756a93ded72b823b19dd877

So if you store a password's MD5 in a database, it is a clever idea to add a salt to it. For example, instead of `md5(password)` you store `md5("salt1234" + password)`. Or, even better, you use a different salt for each user, so nobody can even see which users share the same password.

**Conclusion here:** Mind that even though you can't reverse a hash, you can still look one up, which is easy for unsalted hashes like the above.

Hacking movies and their actions usually rely on brute forcing. But that's not the truth, at all!

Comment: They do not have the same md5. I paste your strings into an md5 hash encoder and get different md5 hashes.

Comment: Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 - These are bytes represented as hexadecimal, not a string.

Comment: no, these are strings and are supposed to be pasted into an md5 hash encoder as is, problem is - you included spaces